# mariadb: ERROR 1286 ... Unknown storage engine 'ndbinfo' when turning on encrypt_binlog

Tags: mariadb

mariabdb version: 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~buster-log

operating system: Debian 10

I'm trying to enable binlog encryption on a mariadb server, which is running as master in a replication configuration. Per the instructions at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/encrypting-binary-logs/, I stopped the server; edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` by adding the line `encrypt_binlog=ON` to the `[mariadb]` section; restarted the server. The restart failed with the error message

ERROR 1286 ... Unknown storage engine 'ndbinfo' when turning on encrypt_binlog

Recursive grep of /etc/mysql/* yields nothing about anything like that being explicitly turned on, as best I can tell. Search engine results are also sparse; I can't find anything on point.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[ndbinfo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-ndbinfo.html) is part of MySQL's cluster and not part of MariaDB. I suspect you upgrade from a MySQL version at some stage. Main thing to check is you're not using the ndb cluster as storage in some way.

Try putting in `skip-plugin-ndbinfo` in your configuration file, and then looking at [show plugins](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-plugins/), and then [uninstalling the ndbinfo plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/plugin-overview/#uninstalling-plugins) and other `ndb*` plugins at the same time.

Comment: I think you're right! I'm too scatter-brained to remember everything I do but I believe I did replace this server's mysql with mariadb (they assured me it would be so easy (-: ) I had begun to pick up the scent, i.e., was suspecting that the mysql/mariadb swapping was involved. But thanks to his insight, I'm now hot on the trail. Thank you.